# Flutter default color value

Tags: android, flutter, dart, colors, default-value

How can i set this correctly in constructor? Provided that the value of the first field can be set differently than the default, and the second field should always use withAccent

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can make your class constructor private and create a factory constructor to implement your custom initialization logic like following:

```dart
class Foo {
  final Color sliderDefaultColor;
  final Color sliderActiveColor;

  Foo._({
    required this.sliderDefaultColor,
    required this.sliderActiveColor,
  });

  factory Foo(Color color) {
    return Foo._(
      sliderDefaultColor: color,
      sliderActiveColor: color.withRed(10),
    );
  }
}
```

Then you can instantiate class like this:

```dart
final foo = Foo(Colors.blueGrey);
```

Comment: And what if I need to either accept a color or set a defColor.withAccent(10)? previously, I just didn't pass the color, and when applying the color, I checked it for null, now I want to switch to null-safety, and don't know how do it right

Comment: For example: 

TestClass(Colors.green, Colors.red);
default = Colors.green
active = Colors.red

TestClass(Colors.green);
default = Colors.green
active = default.withRed(10)